# Check if char contains a number, dash or parentheses

Tags: ios, objective-c, char

Given `char` how can I check if it is either numeric, contains a dash `-` or contains a left or right brace? `()`

Comment: Are we talking about a single `char` or a string of `char`s?  And since we're talking iOS, is it a true C `char`, or a `unichar` returned from an NSString object?

Comment: Use ASCII or what @rmaddy showed. ASCII version (C char): `if (myChar => 48 || myChar <= 57 || myChar == 45 || myChar == 91 || myChar == 93)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

```
char ch = ... // some char
If (ch == '-' || ch == '{' || ch == '}' || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the parameters than you can choose which character you would like for example:

```
char ch = "-";
cout << "Enter date (month-day-year): " << endl;
cin << month << ch << day << ch << year;
cout << month << ch << day << ch << year << endl;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30196071)